# PHP preg_match from string

Tags: php, regex

I have this string :

```
$content = 'Hello <!--blapi[getinfoprix("prix_p1"=>"1-6048df6;image/purchase-small.png"]--> Hello<!--blapi[prix_p1->description]-->';
```

How can i get the two string `<!--*-->` in an array[2]?

I've made this :

```
$pattern = '/<!--blapi\[(.*)\]-->/sU';
preg_match($pattern, $content, $matches);
```

But I have this result :

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(74) "<!--blapi[getinfoprix("prix_p1"=>"1-6048df6;image/purchase-small.png")]-->"
  [1]=>
  string(60) "getinfoprix("prix_p1"=>"1-6048df6;image/purchase-small.png")"
}
```

I don't understand why it's ignoring the second string `<!--blapi[prix_p1->description]-->`...

I've used the flag "U". Maybe there is a better pattern for what I want to do?

EDITION :
I expect this result :

```
Array
(
    [0] => getinfoprix("prix_p1"=>"1-6048df6;image/purchase-small.png"]
    [1] => prix_p1->description
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `preg_match_all` should work:

```
$content = 'Hello <!--blapi[getinfoprix("prix_p1"=>"1-6048df6;image/purchase-small.png"]--> Hello<!--blapi[prix_p1->description]-->';
if ( preg_match_all('/<!--.*?\[(.*?)\]-->/', $content, $matches) )
   print_r($matches[0]);
```

#### OUTPUT

```
Array
(
    [0] => getinfoprix("prix_p1"=>"1-6048df6;image/purchase-small.png"
    [1] => prix_p1->description
)
```

Comment: thank's but look my edit please. Only need this kind of string : <!--blapi[*]-->

Comment: Your edit is still unclear on what output are you expecting. Can you show that in your questio.

Answer (score 1):

```
$pattern = '~<!--(blapi\[(?:.*?)\])-->~si';
```

**Does this pattern produce the expected results?** I understand you want to capture the `blapi` part too. But not sure...

Changed `.*U` to `.*?` and added `i` for case-insensitive at the end. The inner `blapi` is a non-capture group and the `blapi[...]` is now the capture group.

Also avoid wrapping a regex in `/` as it conflicts with URLs and HTML. Use `~` as it's seldom used and much safer. It's not nice to escape `http://` to `http:\/\/` just because of the wrap character.

You also need `preg_match_all` as `preg_match` capture only one match. It's mostly used for match testing, single-match search but not multiple match search.